# How to pull a number out of a loop each time it runs

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have a question where I need to make a simple program that has you input 2 numbers and then use those as bounds and multiply those numbers and all of them in between. 
i.e.
1 and 4
1*2*3*4=24
This is what I've got, but I can not figure out how to make it do that and I end up making it multiply the last 2 numbers together instead of all of them. I think this is because I can't figure out how to pull the number in the loop out so I could multiply it by the next number it would give me.

```
int main()
{

  int num1,
      num2,
      product = 0,
      total = 0;
  cout << "Enter any two integers(with a space in between: " << endl;
  cin >> num1;
  cin >> num2;

  for (int i = num1; i < num2; i++)
  {
     product = i * (i + 1);
  }
  cout << "The total is: " << product << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I know for sure that I need to do something else to be able to get the product out and be able to multiply it by the next product, but I can not get it to work. I also don't know if it is alright to put the i there an use it to multiply.

Comment: How about `product = product * i;`? And make sure that `product` starts at 1.

Comment: @immibis Thanks! I'm really stupid I spent the last hour trying to figure this out. I was just over thinking it.

Answer (score 0):

You were facing this problem because of your line: `product = i * (i + 1);`
What was happening is that the `product` variable was being overwritten by the product of `i` and `i++`. This was not added to the previous value of `product`. This is why your program only multiplied the last 2 numbers together instead of all of them.

This code below should run as intended:

```
int main()
{

  int num1,
      num2,
      product = 1;   // modified. Plus, total is unused, so you can remove it
      //total = 0;
  cout << "Enter any two integers(with a space in between: " << endl;
  cin >> num1;
  cin >> num2;

  for (int i = num1; i <= num2; i++)  // modified
  {
     product = product * i ;  // modified
  }
  cout << "The total is: " << product << endl;
  return 0;
}
```